# How to import and edit variable from model associated with currently logged in user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to import a variable from a model associated with the currently logged-in user. My model uses a one to one relationship with the built-in User model. After importing the variable I want to change it to True for whatever user is currently logged in.

I've tried messing with my import statement and got it to work correctly It's giving me "PurchaseHistory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'" when trying to edit the variable. I know this is my misunderstanding of a code snippet I found online, and I would just like someone to help me fix it.

```
#models.py
class PurchaseHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    InvestingOne = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        app_label = 'PurchaseHistory'
```

```
#payments/views.py
def charge(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=500,
            currency='usd',
            description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
        post = PurchaseHistory(id=InvestingOne)
        post.InvestingOne = True
        post.save()
        return render(request, 'charge.html')
```

I believe I provided good information to help me fix this. Let me know if there are any additional details I should provide. Thank you.

Edit: Here is my file structure. The only thing I believe that might complicate this is that my model is in the main project folder and my view is in an app named payments.
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6AeL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your model should look like below

```
class PurchaseHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="purchase_history")
    is_one_invested = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'PurchaseHistory'
```

I see you have abstract model, which you can't use in queries https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

make migrations & migrate and go further

```
#payments/views.py
def charge(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=500,
            currency='usd',
            description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if PurchaseHistory.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
                request.user.purchase_history.is_one_invested = True
                request.user.purchase_history.save()

        return render(request, 'charge.html')
```

or if you want to create object instead of updating

```
#payments/views.py
def charge(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=500,
            currency='usd',
            description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            PurchaseHistory.objects.create(user=request.user, is_one_invested=True)

        return render(request, 'charge.html')
```

in Django <= 1.9 use `is_authenticated()` instead of `is_authenticated`

Comment: So the `InvestingOne` is a Model, right? You may add a connection between those two models https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#relationships
I still exactly don't get it what do you want to achieve, could you show me you all code?

Comment: Try with edited answer, didn't see you use Django higher than 1.9

Comment: You are welcome, if you are at begining of journey with Django, I would recommend to start with https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/ and django's documentation.